# PHP code-generation

Tags: php, code-generation

Instead of `eval()` I am investigating the pros and cons with creating .php-files on the fly using php-code.

Mainly because the generated code should be available to other visitors and for a long period of time, and not only for the current session. The generated php-files is created using functions dedicated for that and only that and under highly controlled conditions (no user input will ever reach those code files).

So, performance wise, how much load is put on the webserver when creating .php-files for instant execution using `include()` later elsewhere compared to updating a database record and always query a database at every visit?

The generated files should be updated (overwritten) quite frequently but not very frequent compared to how frequently they will be executed

What are the other pro/cons? Should the possibility of the combination of one user overwriting the code files at the same time as others is currently executing them introduce complicated concurrent conflict solving? Using Mutex? Is it next to impossible to overwrite the files if visitors is constantly "viewing" (executing) them?

PS. I am **not** interested in alternative methods/solutions for reaching "the same" goal, like:

1. Cached and/or saved output buffers, as an alternative, is out of the question, mainly because the output from the generated php-code is highly dynamic and context-sensitive
2. Storing the code as variables in a database and create dynamic php code that can do what is requested based on stored data, mainly because I don't want to use a database as backend for the feature. I don't ever need to search the data, query it for Aggregation, ranking or any other data collecting or manipulation
3. Memcached, APC etcetera. It's not a caching feature I want
4. Stand-alone (not PHP) server with custom compiled binary running in memory. Not what I am looking for here, although this alternative have crossed my mind.

**EDIT:**
Got many questions about what "type" of code is generated. Without getting into details I can say: It's very context sensitive code. Code is not based on user direct input but input in terms of choices, position and flags. Like "closed" objects in relation to other objects. Most code parts is related to each other in many different, but very controlled, ways (similar to linked lists, genetic cells in AI-code etcetera) so querying a database is out of the question. One code file will include one or more others, and so on..

Comment: Do you use a database?

Comment: Yes, I use a database for other features.

Comment: _"no user input will ever reach those code files"_ That may be the plan, but if you give the web server write permission to the files it serves... you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: What kind of liberty is there in the generated PHP pages? Can they be really anything, or do they follow a certain template, where only data differs, but the general rendering is predictable?

Comment: If no user input reaches those files, I find it hard to imagine that you would need methods to write code instead of just writing the code once.

Comment: @Alex I am totally aware of the security risks (main reason for not many articles that is covering this subject)

Comment: @trincot it's very context sensitive code, difficult to explain. I am (as stated in the question) not searching for alternative solutions

Comment: @jeroen No user input as in input fields, but instead a lot of user input in terms of choices/flags

Comment: Sounds like you're building a library system. Therefore simply use a database.

Comment: @Martin Nope, not a library. I have edited the question and added more info about the data below the "EDIT" tag

Comment: this just seems like a bad idea.  why not use a database?  anyway to answer your question, there is a performance hit but it is negligible probably, depending on how many files it is writing and the `effort` involved in creating them.  If they are not unique to the user, then it is possible that they may change `in between` calls.  This could indeed cause a security risk (potentially).

Comment: You're looking in the wrong direction. Since you're not open to alternatives, this is a dead-end question.

Comment: @NappingRabbit Thanks for input. Well, the "data" is structured in a way that if using a database I need about 20 subsequent queries to fetch a single result, instead of inlucing one .php-file (that includes another one, and so on ..) to retrieve the result. Some calculation is also done "between" the recursive includes.

Comment: @trincot dead-end? My question was not about alternatives from the start. I stated that clearly for the sake of clarity. My question is mainly about brainstorming cons about creating .php-files on the fly.

Comment: @Plarsen well most of writing code is figuring out ways to do what you want, so I wont fault you but it still seems likely that a stored-procedure or even multiple db calls would be faster; and definitely more secure.  I suppose you could use a naming convention that ties the files to a user or time, to avoid the mismatch issue.  good luck!

Comment: PHP produces output dynamically. You should use that power. If you are going to add a layer of *also* producing PHP scripts dynamically, you are adding a layer that is duplicating the dynamic feature PHP already provides. Together with a well-designed database, you would get the best solution.

Comment: @NappingRabbit Thanks! Any input on this is valuable. I guess my generated code is best described as nodes in a mesh that is traversed. I have considerated a database, and I also know some advanced multitable SQL tricks, but couldn't find any way to avoid multiple subsequent queries.

Comment: @trincot Point taken. I havn't thought of it like that before. I guess its the many ways the 'include' function can be used that is difficult to simulate using dynamic code and a database. But I am always open minded about a database solution, of course, but as time has passed I have more and more concluded that the queries and DB-design is really complicated for the type of data that I am using. It might turn up I need database design help, but then I will ask a totally different question, based on my data-structure, elsewhere.

Comment: @trincot and others... A database like MySQL is very powerful with complicated queries. Why repeat a query when the data changes at a much lower rate then people actually need the data. A database is not good at everything. MySQL is slow for instance. Redis is very fast, but lacks the query power/flexibility. You need to find a way to combine the two, a hybrid solution. Normally one would store the MySQL result in redis and run PHP on that. But sometimes caching self generated php code can be very effective. I use them for ad serving software (20m+ views/day). MySQL could never handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing in an application. It generates static PHP Code from data in a MySQL database. I store the code in memcached and use ‘eval’ to execute it. Only when something changes in the MySQL database I regenerate the PHP. It saves an awful lot of MySQL reads

Comment: Interesting idea, like a combination of keeping the pros from eval php code while using the pros regarding the update process from the  SQL/memcashed-method. I need to take this into account and see if I can take it one step further and also create fysical .php-files

Comment: You can output physical php files of course, but with the right caching it would come to the same result effectively.